# List Remove in Double loop

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
csvFile = [a,b,c,d,e,...]
brandList = [a,c,e,...]
copyFile = csvFile

for i in csvFile:
    for j in List2:
        if ' '+j.lower()+' ' in ' '+i.lower()+' ':
            print j.lower(), ' ',i.lower()
            copyFile.remove(i)
```

However, after removing an item, the process skips one item. So in a list of [a,b,c,d,e] removing c would skip d entirely (also the print). Be aware that I am not removing from the list I am using to loop. I also tried break. If you remove the "removal-line", print gives me the correct output.

Comment: Don't mutate (eg: `remove`) elements of a list you're iterating over. The name `csvFile` is misleading as it's a list. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: In particular `csvFile` and `copyFile` are two references to the same list. May I suggest you initialize the later as `copyFile = list(csvFile)`.

Comment: @SethMMorton: There is `in`, not `==` operator. It's a poor man's whole word match.

Comment: I don't want "new" to filter "newly", so I need " new ". Then it won't filter words at the beginning or end of the sentence though. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @JanHudec OK.  I deleted my original comment.  Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you *are* removing from the list you are using to loop. Because `copyFile` and `csvFile` point to the same list object. Python has purely referential semantics, so assignment makes the new variable point to the same object as the right hand expression, not a deep copy.

If you want to make a copy, construct a new list:

```
copyFile = list(csvFile)
```

Comment: or ``copyFile = csvFile[:]``

Comment: list() also has the effect that if the original input is an iterable other than a list, it will convert the type to a list, whereas [:] will leave the type alone, so if the input is a tuple, you'll get an error from trying to modify the tuple if you use [:]. On the other hand [:] by specification returns a shallow copy of the original, so if you need a copy without converting the type to a list, use [:].  Also note that while list(listA) returns a copy of the list, tuple(tupleA) returns the original iterable if it is already a tuple.

Answer (score 1):

What it looks like is you can use a regex with multiple conditions, and word boundaries so it only finds whole words, then use that as part of a `filter` to recreate a new matching list:

```
import re

base_items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'the quick letter a jumped over the dog', 'eeeeee I no match...']
look_for = ['a', 'c', 'e']
rx = re.compile(r'\b({})\b'.format('|'.join(re.escape(item) for item in sorted(look_for, key=len, reverse=True))))
res = filter(rx.search, base_items)
# ['a', 'c', 'the quick letter a jumped over the dog']
```

Comment: Looks like much more efficient solution. It might be somewhat advanced for beginners though.